# Coroutines and ViewModel best practice for separation of concers

Tags: android, kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines

I needed some direction on being able to observe some flow as live data in my ViewModel class.

For example: The ViewModel class has the field userDataFlow below which combines a few streams of Data Flow. I want to be able to extract out the work of that field into a separate class and let all of the inner working take place there and just want to observe the LiveData to the field in the ViewModel. I would need to pass in few things in the Parameter of that class from the ViewModel which the Flow would need in order to work. Not sure if this is a good practice. Basically, let my ViewModel observe the result and pass it along to the View.

```
   val userDataFlow: Flow<List<UserData>> = 
   combine(
       familyChannel.asFlow(),
       userRealTimeData.asFlow,  
       ).asLiveData()
}
```

Comment: This code doesn’t make sense. Is it a Flow or a LiveData? You take a Flow returned by `combine` and convert it to a LiveData only to attempt to initialize a Flow property with it. I don’t understand your description of what you’re trying to do.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.. But, as you were talking about separation of concerns, I would add a Repository layer to handle the business-logic, rather than having the ViewModel handling it. Let the ViewModel only prepare the data for the view. Check this out: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a `UseCase`/`Interactor` which in short processes data coming from different repositories.

For example suppose you want a list of your friends that live in countries with a COVID-19 infection rate above a certain value:

```
class GetFriendsInDangerUseCase(
    private val friendsRepository: FriendsRepository,
    private val countryRepository: CountryRepository)

    fun invoke(threshold: Float) = friendsRepository.friendsFlow
        .combine(countryRepository.countriesFlow) { friends, countries ->
            val dangerousCountries = countries.filter { it.infectionRate >= threshold }
            friends.filter { it.country in dangerousCountries }
        }
```

Then use it like this from your VM:

```
val friendsInDangerFlow = getFriendsInDanger(0.5)
```